# Scaled Riemann zeta function with no zero in the critical strip

Tags: nt.number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, l-functions, riemann-hypothesis

***Update**: I added $exp[i\theta_k(s)]$ in the definition of $\eta^*(s)$ to address some critical convergence issues. Thanks for the contributors who pointed to these issues.*

Prime numbers are denoted as $p_1,p_2,\dots$ with $p_1=2$. The modulus of a complex number $s$ is denoted as $|s|$. Finally, $S$ denotes the right half of the critical strip, defined by $\frac{1}{2}<\Re(s)<1$.

Let us assume that one can find a product of the form

$$\eta^*(s)=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\exp[i\theta_k(s)]\cdot\tau_k(s)}{1-p_k^{-s}},$$

converging in $S$, but not necessarily if $\Re(s)=\frac{1}{2}$, thus leaving open the possibility that it has zeroes or is undefined on the critical line. Let us further assume that

- $\theta_k(s)=\arg(1-p_k^{-s})$, with $\arg$ denoting the principal argument
- $\tau_k(s)$ is a strictly positive real number
- $|\eta^*(s)|>0$ if $s\in S$, thus no zero (in other words, the product converges if $s\in S$)
- $\eta^*(s)$ is smooth enough

Would that imply that the Riemann Hypothesis (RH) is true? I guess the answer is *not necessarily*. I can not believe that the answer is yes, otherwise (barring some mistakes in my computations), I have found such a function, and I know that there is no way I  could prove RH. So I am looking for an answer that explains why it does not necessarily imply that RH is true.

Note that if $\tau_k(s)=1$, then $|\eta^*|=|\zeta|$ is the modulus of the traditional zeta function.

Below is my function $\eta^*$ satisfying all the requirements. The methodology to get there can be applied to other Dirichet $L$-functions. It is described in some details in my previous MO question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391178/truncated-euler-products-dirichlet-eta-function-and-convergence-issues) (not at all intended to prove RH), with the core idea explained in the "Update" section, just below the conclusions. The arguments are not very complicated. Instead, the approach (based on finite products ultimately converging) is somewhat unusual and involves some subtleties, and some luck in the sense that there are some rather unexpected simplifications taking place.

**About my re-scaled Riemann zeta product**

Let $s=\sigma + it$. It is defined using

$$\tau_k(s)=\Big[1+\frac{2\cos(t\log p_k)}{p_k^\sigma + p_k^{-\sigma}}\Big]^{-\frac{1}{2}}.$$

It results in

$$|\eta^*(s)|^{-2} = \Big\{\prod_{k=1}^\infty \Big(1+\frac{1}{p_k^{2\sigma}}\Big)\Big\}
\cdot \Big\{\prod_{k=1}^\infty \Big(1-\frac{4\cos^2(t\log p_k)}{p_k^{2\sigma}+p_k^{-2\sigma}+2}\Big)\Big\}.$$

This simplifies to

$$|\eta^*(s)|^{-2} = \frac{1}{\zeta(2\sigma)}
\cdot \prod_{k=1}^\infty \Big[1-\Big(\frac{2\cos(t\log p_k)}{p_k^{\sigma}+p_k^{-\sigma}}\Big)^2\Big] .$$

The above product converges if $s\in S$, but not always (if ever) when $\Re(s)=\frac{1}{2}$, and never if $\Re(s)<\frac{1}{2}$. And of course, due to the infinite product representation, $\eta^*(s)$ can never vanish if $s\in S$. Again, details are available [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391178/truncated-euler-products-dirichlet-eta-function-and-convergence-issues).

**Conclusions**

Just like $\eta$ (the Dirichlet eta function) is a scaled version of $\zeta$ to study its zeroes in $0<\Re(s)<1$, so is $\eta^*$ in  $\frac{1}{2}<\Re(s)<1$. We have $\eta(s)=(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s)$ and $|\eta^*(s)|=\tau(s)|\eta(s)|$ with $\tau(s)$ being the product of all $\tau_k(s)$, properly defined if $\Re(s)>1$. Both functions $\eta$ and $\eta^*$ are scaled analytic continuations. In particular, $\eta$ is an additive scaling in the sense that it is defined by a series (and thus easy to build but very hard to use to prove RH) while $\eta^*$ is a multiplicative scaling directly defined by an infinite convergent product (thus hard to build but easy to gain insights about RH).

Comment: Of course, I know $\zeta$ has infinitely many zeroes on the critical line. My point is that the above product for $\zeta^*(s)$ is not defined for $\Re(s)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: not sure why you think that the existence of $\zeta^*$ has anything to do with the behavior of $\zeta$ in the strip $1/2 < \sigma \le 1$, its zeroes, RH etc;

Comment: @Conrad: I am not sure myself either, thus my question. I will update this post, maybe it will become more clear what the relation is between $\zeta$ and $\zeta^*$.

Comment: @Conrad: I added a conclusion to my question, hope it helps.

Comment: From what I can see, your conditions on $\tau_k$ do not imply that it $\tau(s)$ converges  anywhere, nor that it is even defined for $\Re(s)>1$ (you only ask for $\tau_k$ to be defined on $S$). Even if defined, $\tau$ cannot be analytic unless it is constant, given your conditions imply it is always real.

Comment: @Wojowu: you need $\sigma>1$ for $\tau(s)$ to converge. If $\sigma\leq 1$, each $\tau_k(s)$ must be attached to its "sister" factor $(1-p_k^{-s})^{-1}$  to make $\zeta^*(s)$ to converge.  You can't separate them if $\sigma\leq 1$. This is the same as saying you can separate $1-2^{1-s}$ from $1^{-s}+2^{-s}+3^{-s}+\cdots$ in the $\eta$ function. You can do it if $\sigma>1$, not if $\sigma\leq 1$.

Comment: You only demand that $\tau_k(s)$ be defined if $s\in S$. If $\sigma>1$ then $s\not\in S$, so $\tau(s)$ won't converge, nor even need $\tau_k(s)$ be defined

Comment: Sorry my previous reply was wrong, I deleted it. Actually, the larger $\sigma>1$, the faster the product for $\tau(s)$ will converge. If $\sigma\leq 1$ that product diverges. One problem I am interested in is computing $\zeta^*(1)$. We have $\eta(1)=\log 2$, and I am hoping I can get an exact known math constant for $\zeta^*(1)$ as well. I also need things to work out for $\sigma>1$ in order to be able to claim (scaled) "analytic continuation".

Comment: regarding the conclusion, in what sense is $\zeta^*$ analytic? definitely not complex analytic even for $\Re s >1$ as the ratio of two analytic functions cannot be real nonconstant;

Comment: @Conrad: I am working on changing $\zeta^*$. Right now it has become $\eta^*$ but more changes are needed.

Comment: @Wojowu: my question in its current form is beyond repair. I may try one last thing, but I hesitate between deleting this question / writing a new one, or updating the question. What would you suggest?

Comment: Right now you can take $\tau_k(s)$ to be the absolute value of $1-p_k^{-s}$, which would render all factors equal to $1$. The resulting product indeed has no zeros for $s\in S$, but that is not known to imply RH.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't thought about that, you are right. Not sure if there are other counter-examples. I will continue to look into this. And anyway, as I said, I can't imagine myself being able to prove RH, not even in a small sub-strip for the most basic $L$-function (other than finite products, which are irrelevant)

Comment: in this last form, not sure why you want the $1-2^{1-s}$ term as that changes nothing in terms of convergence etc - just adds some zeroes on $\Re s =1$; second with the choice of $\theta_k(s)=\arg(1-p_k^{-s})$ it looks like the product is one of positive numbers $\frac{\tau_k(s)}{|1-p_k^{-s}|}$, so not sure what has that to do with RZ where a lot of the subtlety is in the argument

Comment: Yes $1-2^{-s}$ should be removed, but I've made already many edits. I will remove it later for sure.

Comment: @Conrad: I think if any progress has to be made, it needs to be shown on a very simple function with known roots in the critical strip, that the re-scaling / analytic continuation works. In essence, you need a theorem about "root-preserving scaled analytic continuations of infinite products", showing how it works on a more basic function before applying it to RH. I will ask a question about that. Examples will be so simple that actually it will be about an analytic continuation on the real line. from $]1,\infty]$ to $\frac{1}{2},\infty]$.

Comment: @Conrad: The function $\eta^*(s)$ is defined on $\mathbb{C}$ but takes only real values. For instance, if $\tau_k(s)=1$, then $\eta^*(s)=|\zeta(s)|$.

Comment: @Wojowu: I am working (with anyone who wants to help) on a theorem about "root-preserving scaled analytic continuations of infinite products". The example you mentioned, $\tau_k(s)=|1-p_k^{-s}|$ would not meet the requirement of that theorem. Indeed if just one of the $\tau_k(s)$ (say for $k=3$) is equal to $|1-p_k^{-s}|$, it would not meet the conditions of that theorem.

Comment: What puzzles me is in what sense you talk about $\eta^*$ being analytic continuation because that function is not analytic

Comment: @Conrad: What about $1/(\eta^*)^2$? At least that one has all the square roots gone.

Comment: it is unclear what smoothness does the product have - the factors are not (complex) analytic so the usual normal convergence theorem for holomorphic products doesn't apply; the product is continuous and I could buy differentiable infinitely many times (though would need proof as infinite products are tricky in general) but not sure about any kind of analyticity

Comment: @Conrad: Thank you for your useful comments. I have no doubt I am very far away from proving RH, and at  the same times I am trying to bring a new approach (products rather than sums or integrals), but as you said, in the end, if my  function $\eta^2(s)$ is not indefinitely differentiable, (and proving it may be as hard as proving RH), then the "analytic continuation" argument fails.

Comment: @Conrad: I have very little leeway in my choice for $\tau_k(s)$. Essentially, I am trying to extend $\eta^*(s)$ from $\Re(s)>1$ to $\Re(s)>\frac{1}{2}$. Essentially, it is almost like trying to make $\prod(1-1/k^\sigma)$ extend to convergence by multiplying it by $\prod(1+1/k^\sigma)$. Both considered separately are divergent if $\sigma>1$, but when blended together in the right way, it converges if $\sigma>1/2$. This is just an analogy. Replace $\prod(1+1/k^\sigma)$ by $\prod(1+ (1+2^{-1000000})/k^\sigma)$, and convergence fails. This is how much lille leeway I have.

Comment: @Conrad: Regarding analytic continuation, I will say this. It two functions $a(s), b(s)$ have analytic continuation, does $a^2(s)+b^2(s)$ have analytic continuation? If there is a theorem saying so, then analytic continuation is no longer a problem in my case. But the choice of $\tau(s)$ still remains an issue.

Comment: @Wojowu: The example $\tau_k(s)=|1-p_k^s|$ makes the whole argumentation fails as you pointed out, and I agree. Even if that was the case for just one $k$ alone (say $k=3$), it would make my argumentation to fail. The more I think about it, including such a factor is similar to potentially introducing a $\frac{0}{0}$ in the product. You need to first test the mechanics on a product that does actually have zeroes, like $f(x,s)=\prod_k (1-x/k^s)$ (then $x=k^s$ is a root).

Comment: @Wojowu: Assume $x, s$ are real. The product converges if $\Re(s)> 1$. Multiply it by $\prod_k(1+x/k^s)$. Now it converges if $\Re(s)>1/2$, it is an analytic continuation, and sure I added a bunch of new roots which can be proved to NOT being roots of the original $f(x,s)$. But in essence, I preserved the roots of the original function $f$. Now think about $f(s)=\prod_k(1-ix/k^s)$. Multiplying by $\prod(1+ix/k^s)$ to extend analyticity, I would kill all the roots of the original function in the process. That is why we need a theorem about root-preserving when making such manipulations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditions presented are contradictory - for any $s=\sigma+it\in S$ with $t\neq 0$ it is impossible to choose positive real numbers $\tau_k(s)$ such that $\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\tau_k(s)}{1-p_k^{-s}}$ converges. This is because the argument of the partial product cannot converge, and this is something that positive real $\tau_k(s)$ can fix.

I will omit the details, but the idea is similar to that in my answer to your previous question. For some $n\in\mathbb N$ let $N=e^{2\pi n/t}$ and consider the product over primes in the interval $[e^{2n\pi/t+\pi/2t},e^{2n\pi/t+\pi/t}]$. By prime number theorem, there are $\gg N/\log N$ primes in this interval. For each such prime we have $\Im(p_k^{-s})\gg N^{-\sigma}$, and so we deduce the the argument of $1-p_k^{-s}$ is $\gg N^{-\sigma}$. The increase in the argument coming from all primes in this interval is $\gg N^{1-\sigma}/\log N$, which diverges. Hence the product can't converge.

Given the basic premise of the question is faulty, this voids the entirety of the rest of the question.

Comment: In my previous question, I was dealing with a product equivalent (w.r.t convergence) to a series whose $k$-th  term is $\sim \cos(t\log p_k)/p_k^\sigma$. It could never converge, agreed. Here by rescaling I fixed the issue: the $k$-th term is equivalent to $\sim  \cos(t\log p_k)/p_k^{2\sigma}$. And since $\sigma>1/2$, meaning $2\sigma>1$,  it actually always converge. That was the whole purpose of this new post (fixing the problem in the previous one) and I think you missed it.

Comment: I think in turn you missed the point of my answer. By taking absolute values you are ignoring the argument of the terms, and the argument is what prevents the product from converging.

Comment: The equivalent of argument in the series expansion is the imaginary part of the summands, and this is something you cannot adjust by multiplying by real numbers.

Comment: Introducing one factor won't impact convergence of the product.

Comment: why do you think that will make the product converge? the eta function doesn't have a product in the critical strip either for the same reasons as zeta as the arguments behave wildly

Comment: @Conrad: more changes are needed. More about this later today.